# How to read in a file of mixed data types into a string in C

Tags: c, file, input

I am trying to read in a file that is formatted like this sample:

```
3 3 1.5 50
0 2 46.0 0
* 1 46.0 1
2 * 46.0 0
0 0 50.0 0 
* * 42.0 0
2 2 36.1
2 1 42 0
0 1 48.0 0
1 0 48 0
```

First I want to store the contents of the file in a string. Then, I want to scan through the string and see if there are any asterisks *. For some reason I can't get it to store as a string. Whenever I try to print the string, it gives me blank lines. Is there an easy way to read in data from a file and store it into a string? I will later convert the numerical data into arrays.

Code snippet:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){ 

  FILE *id; //Input Data
  double *detect; 
  int nx, ny, i, j, k, n, count, t, frequency;
  double a;
  char val;

  n = 0;

  id = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  frequency = atoi(argv[2]);

 if(id){
   fscanf(id, "%d %d %lf %d", &nx, &ny, &a, &tn);
  }

  detect = (double *) malloc(nx*nx*4*sizeof(double)); 

  if(id){
    for(i=0; i<2; i++){
      fscanf(id,"%s", (detect+i));
    }
  }  


//~ The rest of the code is left out ~


return 0;
}
```

Comment: `*` cannot be read using `%d`. Fastest fix: use `%c` and check if the read value is `*` else use it as a number.

Comment: Why do you use `double` type to read as a string?

Comment: Use `getline` function to read lines from file.

Comment: The line of code where I store the first line of the input file works fine. I need those values later on in the code. The second fscanf is the problem @LPs

Comment: @BLUEPIXY That is just a sample input file. Some of the real values could potentially be extremely large.

Comment: Why are you allocating `nx * sizeof(double)` bytes?

Comment: @sameerkn I tried to use getline, but it had errors when it encountered spaces. I also couldn't get it to read in enough lines and I couldn't put it into an if statement to check to see if a * was found in the file (that was stored into a string).

Comment: Use [fgets](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets).

Comment: @LPs You're right, I made a mistake when I used nx*sizeof(double). I will try to use fgets and see if I encounter any problems. Thanks!

Comment: But is still weird to use a `double *` to read strings....

Comment: `getline` will be able to read spaces. Since you want all the line, so would suggest using c++ so that you can easily create vector/array of strings read from file. Also once you read a line in `buffer` then using `buffer[0]` you can decide whether the first character of line is `*`.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code: indent after EVERY opening brace '{'.  unindent before EVERY closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces as that is wide enough to be visible even with variable width fonts.  2) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: When calling `fopen()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: in C, the returned type from a call to a heap allocation function (malloc, calloc, realloc) is `void*`, which can be assigned to any other pointer.  Casting the returned value just clutters the code and adds complexity when trying to understand, debug, maintain the code.

Comment: never access beyond `argv[0]` without first checking `argc` to assure the command line parameter was actually entered.  Should also, when not the proper number of parameters, to output to `stderr` a `usage` message similar to: `fprintf( stderr, "USAGE: %s <parm1> <parm2>\n", argv[0] );`

Comment: the posted code does not compile. Always enable all the warnings when compiling. (for gcc, at a minimum use: -Wall -Wextra -pedantic I also use: -Wconversion -std=gnu99 ).   When asking a question about a runtime problem, as your question is, post code that cleanly compiles, is short, and still exhibits the problem.

Comment: per the question, the first entry on a line of the input file could be a `*`, which cannot be read via a `%d`.  (another good reason to check the returned value from `fscanf()`) so the call to `malloc()` will be passed what ever garbage (or left over data from a prior input line) in the variable: `nx`

Comment: when calling any heap allocation function: (malloc, calloc, realloc) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: in the posted code, if the `fopen()` fails, then the line: `detect = (double *) malloc(nx*nx*4*sizeof(double));` will still be executed, however, the variable `nx` will contain what ever garbage was on the stack where the variable `nx` is located.

Comment: per the question, the lines of the input file contain several spaces. so this line: `fscanf(id,"%s", (detect+i));` will fail at the first encountered space. (%s stops inputting at the first 'white space' encountered.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the data into a string like this.

It uses the following:

1. [`fgets`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm) to read each line from the file and store in a string buffer.
2. [`malloc`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_malloc.htm) to allocate space for string, `char *detect` on the heap. Uses [`realloc`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_realloc.htm) to reallocate more space when needed.
3. [`strcat`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcat.htm) to append `buffer` to the pointer `*detect`.
4. [`free`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_free.htm) to deallocate memory requested by `malloc()`.

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFSIZE 100
#define STARTSIZE 10

int
main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *id;
    char *detect;
    char buffer[BUFFSIZE];
    size_t slen, currsize = STARTSIZE, len = 0;
    const char *separate = " ";

    id = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (!id) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "Error reading file");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    detect = malloc(currsize * sizeof(*detect));
    if (!detect) {
        printf("Error allocating memory\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    *detect = '\0';
    while (fgets(buffer, BUFFSIZE, id) != NULL) {
        slen = strlen(buffer);
        len += slen-1;
        if (slen > 0) {
            if (buffer[slen-1] == '\n') {
                buffer[slen-1] = '\0';
            } else {
                printf("Error: Exceeded Buffer length of %d.\n", BUFFSIZE);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }

        if (currsize == len) {
            currsize *= 2;
            detect = realloc(detect, currsize * sizeof(*detect));
            if (!detect) {
                printf("Error reallocating memory\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }

        strcat(detect, separate);
        strcat(detect, buffer);
    }

    printf("Your string = %s\n", detect);

    free(detect);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As I Understand from the above code, You declared ***detect*** pointer as Double. In 2nd fscanf you are using ***"%s"*** to read data from files as string But ***detect*** pointer is Double type, which is causing the problem. Declare the ***detect*** pointer as ***char***.

```
char *detect;
```

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is create a **structure of all the data type** being stored in a file and **create an array of that struct** depending on the number of lines in the file,then using a loop I will use `fread` to read data into those structures and check my each data type after **explicit conversion to int** of all the data types with **ASCII value of asterisk**.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do so... You can use fscanf, regular expressions, tokenizers, parse generators, finite state machines...

All have advantages and disavantages... fscanf can misbahave with invalid inputs, regular expressions might take too long to parse the whole file, a tokenizer is a complex tool and you might take a while to learn (Flex is the guy for you), and to use FSM you need to really really know what you are doing...